# How does libogg compute the granule position of a packet?

Tags: c, ogg

I can write some code like this using `liboggz`:

```
OGGZ *oggz = oggz_open(filename, OGGZ_READ | OGGZ_AUTO);
oggz_set_read_callback(oggz, -1, read_callback, 0);
while ((long n = oggz_read(oggz, 32)) > 0);
oggz_close(oggz);
```

And my `read_callback` will, conceptually, receive a stream of OGG packets. These packets have a granule position. I'm not talking about liboggz's *calculated* granule position, which if I understand correctly calls into the underlying codec to work out the semantics of the granule position. I'm talking about the "raw" granule position of the packet that you access at `packet->op.granulepos`. How is this value calculated?

If I read about the OGG format on Wikipedia, as far as the file format is concerned the only thing that has a granule position if an OGG *page*, not a packet. Packets can straddle multiple pages and many packets can be on a single page. How does `liboggz` (which I presume calls `libogg` in the background) assign granule positions to individual packets?